# Do YouTube videos buffer for offline playback on Google's iOS app?

Tags: iphone, youtube

I want to preload a 58 minute youtube video on my free home wireless and listen to it later while i'm jogging (so that i can listen without streaming on my limited data plan). Can this be done?  Will the youtube app let you prebuffer an entire video and let you watch it offline?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you don't quit the YouTube app after it loads. You can also do this with the YouTube website; play a video, it starts loading the video with a QuickTime-like player, and you will see it buffer. If you start playing the video in the Safari and exit Safari (while it's still in the background), you can double-tap the home button to bring up the audio controller and hit Play.